# Error while inserting values to table : Incorrect Date Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

So I have created a table with several date values of which one column is not mandatory, meaning it may go with null value. In the table structure, I have set "NULL" as "YES" and "DEFAULT" as "NULL" but every time I try to make an entry with NULL value in the column, it throws error :
Incorrect date value: '' for column `my_column` at row 1. Although when I am entering any date for this column instead of null, the values are inserted successfully.

Comment: An empty string is not `NULL`.

Comment: But it works for the other columns. I was facing same issue with columns with value types text and varchar and the issue was resolved upon setting NULL as yes and DEFAULT as null

Comment: An empty string is a valid value for a VARCHAR, but not for a date.

Comment: Oh Okay!! Thank you!! I tried sending NULL when ' ' is received in input and it works!